# RegisterType, type arguments cannot be inferred

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ioc-container, autofac

I am following [this tutorial](http://tomislavbabicnet.blogspot.com/2013/03/build-application-using-aspnet-mvc-4.html) and I have encountered a problem with the code given for the configuration of *Autofac*. The code give on the tutorial is as follows:

```
public class AutofacConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly);
        builder.RegisterType().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerApiRequest().InstancePerHttpRequest();
        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

When I copy this code into my *MVC* project I get a compile error on this line:

```
builder.RegisterType().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerApiRequest().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

The exception thrown is:

```
 Error 1 The type arguments for method 'Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterType<TImplementer>(Autofac.ContainerBuilder)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
```

I have installed *Autofac* version 3.1.1 with *NuGet*. I guess something has changed in the *Autofac* API since the tutorial was written, but I have never worked with *Autofac* so have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Shoudnt you pass something into RegisterType? or use a type argument?

Comment: @aL3891 Clearly I must pass something into RegisterType because I see it is a generic method. I am trying to figure out, though, if this is a mistake in the tutorial or if something has changed in *Autofac*. I also am not clear on what the line in question is actually trying to do as I don't know what methods *AsImplementedInterfaces*, *InstancePerApiRequest* and *InstancePerHttpRequest* do.

Comment: What I mean is that in your posted code, you don't :)

Comment: To code in the linked tutorial is wrong/incomplete. You need to write either `builder.RegisterType<MyType>()` or `builder.RegisterType(typeof(MyType))`

Comment: @nemesv Thanks. I suspected that it was wrong, but was surprised that no one commented on it at the bottom of the tutorial. I will comment the line out in my code until I figure out what type needs to go in there.

Comment: I figured out what type needs to go in there: *BreezePersonRepository*. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BruceHill - Could you write an answer to this question and accept it? I'm having the same problem.